# Wsus only allow some updates?

Tags: wsus, update

Right now, from fresh install it looks like WSUS downloads all available updates for the product I've selected (win 7). I don't have any nvidia stuff in my environment, is there a way to make wsus download only applicable updates/drivers to my environment? or do i have to do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSUS will not download an update unless it is needed by a client computer. Just because an update is approved doesn't mean that it's been downloaded. If it has actually been downloaded, then a computer on your network needs it.

Comment: hmm weird i guess we can see who needs it through the console right?

Comment: There is a very robust report generator in WSUS 3. Take advantage of it.

Comment: Quick question. The all updates, is it all updates available from microsoft? or jsut all updates avialable on the wsus server?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Can you be more clear and perhaps provide a relevant screenshot?

Comment: In the WSUS console, on the left side under Update Services/ServerNAME/Updates, there is All Updates. All the updates in this Update View, are they all updates available from microsoft regardless of whatever computers need or are they all updates that any computer need?

Comment: Those are any updates for your WSUS server regardless of status. If they haven't been approved, then they aren't downloaded yet.

Comment: i'm asking you that because i see a lot of drivers that none of our computer need. And it shows 1148 updates for the following filters Unapproved and Any.

Comment: If you need to ask another question about this, you should rather than carrying on a discussion in comments. Take some screenshots and ask a new question.